# When i import my JSON into my wallet it says invalid, so I'm using JSONLint and it gives Error: Parse error on line 9: Expecting 'STRING', got 'EOF'

Tags: json, json.net, parse-error, jsonlint, keystore-access

This is how the code is with all its quotation marks placed below

{"address":"abc123a0b123b123ab12345b1abcd12345d12a123","id":"12ab1234-12b1-12ab-1234-1ab12345abc1","version":3,"crypto":{"cipher":"abc-123-abc","cipherparams":{"iv":"ab1234abcd123a1bc12a123a1234b12"},

Comment: Obviously your JSON is incomplete, and the next item out to be the key of a key-value pair, therefore a string.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ formats incomplete JSON for you so you should be able to see exactly where your JSON is truncated.  Anyway, what is your question?  If you are asking, ***Is this JSON invalid?***, well then the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 0):

Ur json has invalid format. Try [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) resource for checking JSONs.